# How to redirect the page on button click as well as save the data in the database

Tags: php, mysql

When i  click the save button after filling the form it should be saved in the database as well as should be redirected to the edit page where i can edit the fields.

Comment: Send Ajax request on successful return redirect to another page

Comment: but the adding of data is done through ajax only

Comment: @Ninad im typing an example but i will use PDO is that ok ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to `POST` the form to the current page, save your data into the database using your favorite method and then redirecting to the next page.

Take a look at the following example:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Insert into database
    $stmt = "INSERT INTO table (something) VALUES ('".$_POST['data']."')";

    // Redirect
    header("Location: nextpage.php");
    exit;
}
?>

<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" role="form">
    <div>
        <label for="data">Your data to insert into the database</label>
        <input type="text" name="data" id="data" placeholder="Data to insert">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```